# Glide download image and save as file synchronously

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm trying to download an image from a URL using Glide and get the path of the file and forward it to `WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent` to be set as a wallpaper.

I found that this can be done using `asFile` method of Glide

Kotlin:

```
val data = Glide
    .with(context)
    .asFile()
    .load(url)
    .submit()
```

But when I call `data.get()` I get the error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a background thread`

So followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/8608146) answer and implemented `MyAsyncTask`

```
interface AsyncResponse {
    fun processFinish(output: File?)
}

class MyAsyncTask(delegate: AsyncResponse) : AsyncTask<FutureTarget<File>, Void, File?>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: FutureTarget<File>?): File? {
        return p0[0]?.get()
    }

    private var delegate: AsyncResponse? = null

    init {
        this.delegate = delegate
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: File?) {
        delegate!!.processFinish(result)
    }
}
```

And I'm doing this now

```
fun getFile(context: Context, url: String) : File {
    val data = Glide
        .with(context)
        .asFile()
        .load(url)
        .submit()

    val asyncTask = MyAsyncTask(object : AsyncResponse {
        override fun processFinish(output: File?) {
            println(output?.path)
        }
    }).execute(data)

  return asyncTask.get()
}
```

But I can't seem to get the `File`

**Edit:**
It was working but now there's a new error

```java
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER dat=content://com.rithvij.scrolltest.provider/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/efebce47b249d7d92fd17340ecf91eb6b7ff86f91d71aabf50468f9e74d0e324.0 flg=0x1 pkg=is.shortcut }
```

Full stack trace

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rithvij.scrolltest, PID: 2760
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER dat=content://com.rithvij.scrolltest.provider/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/efebce47b249d7d92fd17340ecf91eb6b7ff86f91d71aabf50468f9e74d0e324.0 flg=0x1 pkg=is.shortcut }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1816)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4396)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4355)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4679)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4647)
        at com.rithvij.scrolltest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:71)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

1. Now my question is is this the preferred way to set wallpaper from a url?
2. How to deal with the other error?

Comment: what is the result of WallpaperManager.isWallpaperSupported() and isSetWallpaperAllowed() ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I did request `SET_WALLPAPER` permission and it did work with other URIs eg: from a drawable

Comment: Then its most probably due to URI. Sharing file with other apps has changed in android and directly sharing url of file may not work.

Comment: See this tutorial if your not following it already: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing

Comment: I did spend 3 hours on this to lose rep and gain nothing. thanks, people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

1. It is better to use [`downloadOnly()`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#downloadOnly--) as suggested by Elli White [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009104/8608146).
   But I wasted enough time on researching this question and I got a working solution so I decided not to start from scratch.
2. The error I got was because of the image file name that's being returned by Glide.

I fixed it by copying the file somewhere and using it as the source.

```
        val file = asyncTask.get()
//        copy file
        val tempFile = File.createTempFile("image", ".png")
        copyFile(file!!.inputStream(), FileOutputStream(tempFile))
```

And for my use case i.e. to set the image as wallpaper I need not worry about the file extension as long as I specify that it's an image `.png` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question about getting image from url, instead of using `asFile`, it is recommended that you use the method [`downloadOnly()`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#downloadOnly--). Then, rather than using an `AsyncTask`, you can leverage a [`RequestListener`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html) to get an async callback when the resource is loaded.

As for your second question, you are broadcasting an Implicit Intent that is not registered by the OS or any apps on your device. Rather than broadcasting an intent, you can try leveraging the [`WallpaperManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager) System Service.

Comment: I am using WallpaperManager as `wallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent()` mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(android.net.Uri))

Comment: Is that an Implicit Intent that is not registered by the OS?

Comment: I missed that part of your question, my apologies!